Grouping by identifier from an R dataframe to turn repeat rows into columns
I am relatively new to R and struggling to find a solution to this problem.
I have a dataframe from experimental data in R that has two columns - a sample Name and associated Value
e.g
  Name     Value
1 A        8
2 B       10
3 A       14
4 A       12
5 C       12
6 B       5
7 C       3
8 B       15
9 C       7

...
etc
Each Name appears on multiple rows of the full dataframe representing repeats in the experiment this data came from and the associated output Value, in a random order. I would like to combine rows that have the same Name identifier into one row with multiple columns - one for each repeat measurement Value e.g
  Name    Value1   Value2   Value3 ...etc
1 A       8        14       12
2 B       10       5        15
3 C       12       3        7

They closest function I have found to do what I want is the group_by() function from the dplyr library - but this totals the values together, while I want to keep them separate in different columns. This is a better format for exporting to another software I will be using for downstream analysis
Is there a way to adapt this function or another function I can use?
Thanks!
